# Как сделать изменение целого блока , подгружая его из php с помощью ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Смог реализовать на javascript , css ,html , но это слишком скажется на оптимизации сайта.
https://codepen.io/vadimmbld/pen/MWyXNjz

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.part').on('click',function(){
        let i = $(this).index();
        if(!$(this).hasClass('current')){
            if(!$('.content').eq(i).hasClass('current')){
                $('.part').removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');
                $('.content').removeClass('current');
                $('.content').addClass('no-display');
                $('.content').eq(i).removeClass('no-display');
                $('.content').eq(i).addClass('current');
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Подскажите статью как реализовать вот такой переход с помощью ajax и php (если вместо надписи Страница1 и Страница2 будет длинный контент ,например при помощи помощи этого фильтровать товары), решение на wordpress приветствуется.

Вот "живой пример"(фильтр): https://elson.qodeinteractive.com/shop-compact/

Comment: Честно говоря, не понятно, в чем именно сложность. Вы не знаете в принципе, как что-то подгрузить аяксом? Ну информации такой полно. А *целый блок* или маленький - какая разница? Формируйте в php нужный блок, принимайте его в js и пихайте в нужный контейнер.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов , а можно ли как-нибудь запретить вход на дополнительный файл php?

Comment: Если идея в том, чтобы через ajax ваш php был доступен, а напрямую в браузере - нет, то никак. Ведь ajax запрос ничем от обычного не отличается. Или я неправильно понял вас?